# How to store inner text of nodes with same names to a List?

Tags: c#, xml, list, nodes

Using C#, I need to store all the data of the inner text of Email nodes into a list, and all the data of the inner text of Related nodes into a list for each person separately. For now I was only able to store only first "email" node and first "related" node into lists. I get this:

[image]

,when I should get this

[image].

How to get the right answer? This is my xml file:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<People>
  <Person>
    <Name>Toni</Name>
    <Email>a@g.c</Email>
    <Email>b@g.c</Email>
    <Email>c@g.c</Email>
    <Related>Friend1</Related>
    <Related>Friend2</Related>
  </Osoba>
  <Osoba>
    <Name>Deni</Name>
    <Email>d@g.c</Email>
    <Email>e@g.c</Email>
    <Email>f@g.c</Email>
    <Related>Friend3</Related>
    <Related>Friend4</Related>
  </Osoba>
</People>
```

Comment: Show how you extract the data.

Comment: These tags look wrong to me, you've got "<Person>" closed off with "</Osoba>. I also don't see how you can use the field names "Email" or "Related" multiple times in the same record. Whatever code created that XML file is drunk.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the following xml Instead of the one you posted since it is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<People>
  <Person>
    <Name>Toni</Name>
    <Email>a@g.c</Email>
    <Email>b@g.c</Email>
    <Email>c@g.c</Email>
    <Related>Friend1</Related>
    <Related>Friend2</Related>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Deni</Name>
    <Email>d@g.c</Email>
    <Email>e@g.c</Email>
    <Email>f@g.c</Email>
    <Related>Friend3</Related>
    <Related>Friend4</Related>
  </Person>
</People>
```

I am using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).(Another way is to use [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
        String path = "Path of your xml file";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var nodes = doc.Descendants("Person");
        foreach (XElement node in nodes)
        {
            var name = node.Element("Name").Value;
            var emails = node.Elements("Email").Select(x => x.Value);
        }
```